# Run angular function when scroll to up in chat app (pagination)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll, pagination

I have a chat app and I want design a pagination on scroll up event (NOT DOWN). I need a directive for this job.Also I want to show preloader in new page data load. How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi its bit unclear what you really require.
I have just captured up scroll event in a directive hope this helps you.
[updated](http://jsfiddle.net/kavinhuh/17hca7wa/7/)

```
 myApp.directive('scrolly', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var raw = element[0];
        console.log('loading directive');
            raw.scrollTop=300;
        element.bind('scroll', function () {
            console.log(raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight);
            if(raw.scrollTop < lastScrollTop)
          {
         // alert("scroll up");
          lastScrollTop = raw.scrollTop;
          }
          else{
          lastScrollTop = raw.scrollTop;
          }

            if (raw.scrollTop ==0) {
                scope.$apply(attrs.scrolly);
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Thanks but when I open page my scroll is bottom and I want user scroll to top (begin), I fire a event. like Telegram

Comment: @Ehsan I am still unclear of your requirement,I have just triggered an event when you scroll to the top of the list, I hope you are looking for this.